# Obtain relative site URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, angularjs, classic-experience

I need to save a relative URL to a SharePoint subsite in the html controller of an Angular app I'm deploying directly to a page.  I need the URL to be dynamic, so that when I save this site as a template, the URL will point to whatever the current site is.

In my HTML controller, I tried using

```
<a href="~site/List/ListName/AllItems.aspx">
```

This seems to work partially?  It will print the current site, but then instead of it looking like "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/HR/List/ListName/AllItems.aspx"  it prints it as "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/HR/~site/List/ListName/AllItems.aspx"

Am I doing something wrong or will I need to get the current site programmatically via REST?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... just decided to use an HTML relative URL.  Using:

```
./Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx
```

worked fine.